# Expected response to contain an object but got an array for GET action

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-services

I'm getting this error "`Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action 'get'. Expected response to contain an object but got an array`"

and I don't know how to fix it. I have this service

```
angular.module('messages').factory('Messages', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/messages/:username', {
            username: '@username'
        });
    }]);
```

and this in controller:

```
    $scope.findOne = function () {
        $scope.messages = Messages.get({
            username: $routeParams.username
        });

        console.log($scope.messages);
    };
```

For this route I have in API controller this

```
exports.read = function (req, res) {
    res.json(req.message);
};
```

I know that I have to use $resource action isArray = true, but I don't know where to put it. I tried to do something like this:

```
angular.module('messages').factory('Messages', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/messages/:username', {
            username: '@username'
        }, 
            {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}});
    }]);
```

but without result and still same error.

Comment: make isArray to false

Comment: Yep @Anita `{'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});` as your response is an object not an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller:

```
$scope.findOne = function () {
        $scope.messages = Messages.query({
            username: $routeParams.username
        });

        console.log($scope.messages);
    };
```

`query` Instead of `get`, should solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Use Messages.query(...) instead of method get()

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct, but you have the use the method you just created ('query'), so the call would look like this:

```
$scope.findOne = function () {
    Messages.query({
        username: $routeParams.username
    }).$promise.then(function (response) {
        $scope.messages = response;
        console.log($scope.messages);
    });

};
```